# Manipulating values with commas

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I declare a thousand separator in read.csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347410/how-can-i-declare-a-thousand-separator-in-read-csv)

I actually have a solution for this problem, but I am curious if there is a better way to do what I was trying to do.

I scraped some data from the majorleaguesoccer.com and read it into R using

```
mls.reg.tmp <- read.table("../data/mls_reg_season_20100812.csv",
                          header = F, sep = ";")
```

Note that I used sep = ";" because some of the attendance figures where in the thousands on the websites and I scraped "as is", e.g.,

```
> str(mls.reg.dat$a_tot)
 Factor w/ 164 levels " 166,060"," 171,282",..: 132 45 159 153 46 160 
158 148 150 98 ...
```

In hindsight, I should've just removed the commas in python in the pre-processing step of this project.  I should also point out that there were some text fields in the data set as well.

```
> str(mls.reg.dat$team)
 Factor w/ 20 levels "Chicago Fire",..: 4 9 19 11 3 10 13 16 5 6 ...
```

Given that I want to use the attendance data as a numeric value, I converted using as.numeric and gsub.  As an example in a call to ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = mls.reg.dat, aes(x = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", 
  mls.reg.dat$a_tot)), y = sog)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ team)
```

Question:  Is this the most efficient way of working with data such as this?  Or is there a specialized function for doing something along these lines?

I'm posting the question here because I spent quite a bit of time (> 30 min) just working in this simple solution and thought that others might benefit from this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any specialised function, but you could do it directly when you read the data.

```
  data <- read.table(...)
  data$someColumn <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data$someColumn))
```

Any subsequent call can be made using `data$someColumn`, without need of further conversion (and easier-to-read code)

EDIT: seems to be duplicate of ["How can I declare a thousand separator in read.csv?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347410/how-can-i-declare-a-thousand-separator-in-read-csv)

Comment: Thanks; I didn't see that post.